# Scale animations also translating gsap

Tags: javascript, css, css-animations, gsap

I have an svg, and I want four of the elements to pop up in place. I am trying this with gsap but they look like they are flying into place. Here's the code I am using for this

```js
        gsap.fromTo(
            '#ide, #html, #handlebar, #search',
            1.5,
            {
                scale: 0,
            },
            {
                scale: 1,
                yoyo: true,
                ease: 'none',
                repeat: -1,
            }
        );
```

Please also check the [codepen](https://codepen.io/prateekkarki/pen/oNxEZxo) for current working version: https://codepen.io/prateekkarki/pen/oNxEZxo

I don't want them flying from right, I just want them to scale up from their original position. How can I achieve this in GSAP, please help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just remove your CSS that's affecting the transforms:

```
#ide, #html, #handlebar, #search {
  transform-origin: top center;
  transform-box: fill-box;
}
```

[Demo](https://codepen.io/GreenSock/pen/rNeJYOR?editors=0100).

FYI you're more likely to get a faster response on [the GSAP forums](https://greensock.com/forums/).

Comment: Thanks that was very helpful